# What is the meaning of this ampersand and exclamation mark?

Tags: notation

On the top of page 4 of this paper [Direct Construction of Minimal Acyclic Subsequential Transducers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.3698&rep=rep1&type=pdf), there is an expression

$$\forall r \in S\ \forall a \in \Sigma\ \forall \sigma \in \Sigma^*\ ((\mu^*(s,\sigma)=r\ \& \ !\mu(r,a)) \to \lambda(r,a)=[g\mathcal T(\sigma) ]^{-1}g\mathcal T(\sigma a))$$

What's the meaning of the ampersand and the exclamation mark? I guess that $\&$ means "and", but shouldn't it be $\land$?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but I guess authors uses $\&$ to denote 'and' because $\land$ has another meaning.

Comment: $!$ may denotes the negation, but I don't know, I cannot say it with certainty.

Comment: I also though ! might mean negation, but $\mu$ is not a boolean function so I'm not sure. In [\[4\]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.1915&rep=rep1&type=pdf) they say $!\mu(r,\sigma)$ means $\mu(r,\sigma)$ has been defined.

Comment: @tch Thanks for point that out. I think you are right. The author borrowed the notation from that paper.